# I need to excute a stored procedure with a variable inside the call statement

Tags: mysql

I want to write a stored procedure named SpecificCity that will list the students ssn, lastname, address, city, state, and zip living in a specific city. I need to put the specific city in the call statement. I know you guys have helped me before and I could really use your help on this. I dont know if it has to have a delimiter or could it be a simple stored procedure. I dont even know the steps to take and I looked and can't figure out how to do this.

```
    CREATE TABLE student ( SSN CHAR(9) , LastName VARCHAR(25), FirstName VARCHAR(25), MiddleName VARCHAR(25) NULL, Address VARCHAR(50) NULL, City VARCHAR(25) NULL, State CHAR(2) NULL, Zip CHAR(9) NULL, DateOfBirth DATETIME NULL, Salary FLOAT(8,2) not null,
    ParkingSpace INT, Gender CHAR(1) NULL, DptNumber SMALLINT, SuperID CHAR(9), constraint pkField PRIMARY KEY(ssn) ;


    Delimiter //
    create procedure spSpecificCity(IN city VARCHAR(25))
    BEGIN
    SELECT SSN, LASTNAME, ADDRESS, CITY, STATE, ZIP
    FROM STUDENT
    WHERE CITY = CITY;
    END //

    DELIMITER ;

    CALL spSpecificCity('Brooklyn');
```

When I try that it just puts Brooklyn in the city column next to everyname. I am trying but I dont know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

As documented under [Local Variable Scope and Resolution](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/local-variable-scope.html):

> A local variable should not have the same name as a table column. If an SQL statement, such as a [`SELECT ... INTO`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select.html) statement, contains a reference to a column and a declared local variable with the same name, MySQL currently interprets the reference as the name of a variable.

Therefore, you should rename your `city` parameter to something that is distinct from any columns that you wish to reference.  I usually adopt a convention of prefixing local variables with an underscore:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spSpecificCity(IN _city VARCHAR(25))
BEGIN
  SELECT SSN,
         LastName,
         Address,
         City,
         State,
         Zip
  FROM   student
  WHERE  city = _city;
END
```

Alternatively, you could avoid ambiguity by qualifying your column references with a table prefix:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spSpecificCity(IN city VARCHAR(25))
BEGIN
  SELECT student.SSN,
         student.LastName,
         student.Address,
         student.City,
         student.State,
         student.Zip
  FROM   student
  WHERE  student.city = city;
END
```

As an aside, you don't need to use `BEGIN ... END` (nor therefore a change of delimiter) if your procedure contains only a single statement.

Comment: CREATE PROCEDURE spSpecificCity(IN city VARCHAR(25))          BEGIN      SELECT student.SSN,          student.LastName,          student.Address,          student.City,          student.State,          student.Zip   FROM   student   WHERE  student.city = city; END      The where statement is the problem or the in statement is the problem.

Comment: @TanyaMeyers: Copied and pasted into [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8ec10/1/0) - no syntax error there.  Perhaps you could provide further detail?